# Rails 5 Namespace need (in controller) or not (in model) to specify module name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces

In a Models inside the same Module (app/models/**oc**/pedido.rb and  app/models/**oc**/encuadernacion_papel.rb)

I can do this in pedido.rb:

```
class Oc::Pedido < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :encuadernaciones_papel, class_name: "EncuadernacionPapel"
```

--> without "Oc::" in class_name: `has_many :enc... class_name: "Oc::EncuadernacionPapel"`

So, Rails understand EncuadernacionPapel is within Oc Module

I woluld like to omit "Oc::" module name, within "Oc" controllers when call Pedido class, but it crash:

app/controllers/**oc**/firmas_controller.rb

```
class Oc::LiquidacionController < ApplicationController

    Pedido.find(...
```

instead I have to specify:

```
Oc::Pedido.find(...
```

why? is this correct? or I amb missing something?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is due to the way nesting and constant lookup work in ruby. http://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup.html

Comment: thanks for response, Well, I have read posts like this, and I think I understant model nestings and so on, but I thought than inside Rails application controllers and Models may share the same Module...Or should I do anoder module parent of "Oc"  in model and controller?

Comment: If you declare the controller as `module Oc`, `class LiquidacionController` it will lookup `Pedido` from the `Oc` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to take the shortcut when reopening the module:

```
class Oc::LiquidacionController
  def show
    @pedido = Pedio.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

You will get a `NameError: uninitialized constant Oc::LiquidacionController` error since `Oc` is not in `Module.nesting`.  This is because the skipped outer namespaces are not added to`Module.nesting`.

If you instead use the "longhand" form:

```
module Oc
  class LiquidacionController
     def show
        @pedido = Pedio.find(params[:id])
        logger.info( Module.nesting.inspect )
     end
  end
end
```

`Module.nesting` will give you `[Oc::LiquidacionController, Oc]`.